# How to add dynamically user control in wpf application?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a user control `Animator` which take an image and performs animation for that.

Now i want to use this `Animator` to be added from code side.

How to use this ?

In general,
        `<xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MytestApp.Controls">`
Initialization.

and i can use it as

`<local:Animator ImageSource="Images/image.png" Interval="0:0:0.15" HorizontalOffset="50" x:Name="Loader1" Visibility="Hidden" VerticalOffset="50" Height="42" Width="40" ></local:Animator>`

Now i need to add it from my code side. How to use this?

Comment: XY Problem: Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: want to add this user control dynamically.

Comment: @neelbhasim XAML's idea of "dynamically" is really different from other technologies. If you're dealing with `Collection`s of items you should be using an `ItemsControl`. If you're dealing with changing Views dynamically, you should be using a `ContentPresenter` and some `DataTemplate`s. Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for. Try to be more specific about what is your goal and I can tell you the proper way to do what you need, in WPF.

Comment: i want to add the control from the code behind as per selection or count. so that's why i am using the word dynamically.

Comment: You seem to be talking about items, which is what an `ItemsControl` is for. Again, code behind practices are strongly discouraged in WPF.

Answer (score -1):

```
var myAnimator = new MytestApp.Controls.Animator()
myGrid.Children.Add(myAnimator);
```

Comment: how do i add the properties to this?

Comment: not able to view the image which is the main part the control.

Comment: Your Animator is set to Visibility="Hidden", did you change this to "Visible" ? Maby you could post the code of your control...

Comment: Is only the image is not visible or the whole control?